# Can't get into the BIOS/UEFI or see boot output on DisplayPort, but can on HDMI (ASUS Maximus IX Hero)

Tags: boot, bios, hdmi, uefi, displayport

Per the title, this is the extent of my problem. When booting this system, there is *no output* on the screen (or even a signal - the monitor goes to sleep) until Windows comes up and shows me the login screen. Aside from this annoying BIOS/UEFI issue, the computer works normally.

If I connect a monitor via HDMI instead of DisplayPort, then I'm able to see the BIOS/UEFI as expected, boot messages, and so forth. However, due to my workstation setup (HDMI on my monitor is connected to another system), I want to stay on DisplayPort if at all possible

Further, apparently randomly, a 1 long, 3 short beep code is generated on cold boots, which indicates inability to detect the GPU. (This beep does not happen every cold boot, and happens roughly 60% of the time)

However, even on boots where this beep code happens, eventually Windows starts, displays the login screen, and the computer works otherwise normally.

This problem started when I upgraded from a GTX970 to a GTX1070. The 970 did not have this problem, the 1070 and 2080 did.

#### System Specs

- ASUS Maximus IX Hero (BIOS version 1301, 3/14/2018)
- I7-7700K @ 4.2GHz
- 32 GB RAM
- GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER (previously a GeForce 1070, and before that a 970)
- Windows 10 Pro

#### What I have tried

- Setting the Compatibility Support Module to Auto/Enabled/Disabled ([source](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/663941-post-screenbios-doesnt-display-with-displayport/), fixed the problem for someone else)
- Setting PEG as the primary display device in the UEFI/BIOS.
- Installing Windows 10 in UEFI mode (by installing with the CSM set to enabled or auto)
- Disconnecting all devices from the computer aside from the keyboard and display
- An entirely new GPU (Twice!)
- Another DisplayPort monitor
- Another DisplayPort cable
- Modifying the deep sleep, OD, and refresh rate overclock on the monitor.
- Every combination of the above three items
- Upgrading the GPU firmware on the 1070 ([source](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/nv-uefi-update-x64/), references "blank screens on boot until the OS loads")

How do I get the BIOS/UEFI output to show up on my one and only monitor?

Comment: ...did you try all the Displayport outputs with CMS disabled in UEFI mode? This is a known issue with bios past the z87.

Comment: Yes - CSM is currently disabled. I've tried all three settings.

Comment: I don't think the BIOS is simply compatible with the new 10xx, 20xx series in DP. It came out before your GPU even came out after all. I highly suggest you get a good quality HDMI switch. Simply switch between the two systems when needed.

Comment: The last BIOS update for the system came out in 2018, well after the 10xx series released in 2016. The HDMI idea is a decent workaround, but given a lack of wide reporting of this issue (only a couple of forum posts that mentioned toggling the CSM or making other changes fixed the issue on 10xx cards), I'm inclined to think this is some kind of strangeness or misconfiguration rather than a fundamental incompatibility.

Comment: Did you try an older bios by chance? The 1203 doesn't have much differences with the 1301.

Comment: I had this problem back on 1203 as well.

Comment: Perhaps restore BIOS to factory settings ([link](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1030210)), ensuring [USB BIOS Flashback media](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1038568/).

Comment: This took me a while to get around to, but no dice. I downloaded version 1203 and used the flashback mechanism. No effect.

Comment: I'm currently having this same issue with somewhat different hardware: ASUS TUF GAMING B550-PLUS WIFI II Motherboard, AMD Ryzen 7 5700G with Radeon Graphics, and an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950. I think my Windows install is older and non-UEFI so I think I need to leave CSM mode enabled for the time being. Karu, did you ever solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You still have the issue ?

Just purchased a new monitor and was faced with the exact same issue (Gigabyte G32qc)
My new monitor as a option DP 1.3 (120hrtz only) or DP 1.4 (165hrtz+)
DP 1.3 was fine getting into bios
DP 1.4 get the issue no display whilst booting until it gets to windows

This pointed me to my VGA card 2080ti. It's basically a simple DP flash on the VGA card..

You need - NVIDIA_DisplayPort_Firmware_Updater_1.0-x64.exe 100% fix .... PsYmON

Comment: This is the very last item mentioned in the list of things I already tried. On the 2080 Super, it comes back saying that the update isn't applicable to the card.

Comment: Huuuuuge. I have a 1080 and this was what fixed it for me -- my 165hz 1.4 monitor wont display anything until the OS has booted. This solved the problem. BIZARRE that anyone would downvote it.

Comment: The update tool doesn't work for WIn11 (invalidated nvidia certificate).

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of a monitor -- it is common when using Display Port to sometimes not turn on from sleep on powering on (me once in 10-20 boots), at least before the GOP driver takes control. With HDMI (with HDMI CEC at least) it is a less common issue as it is tested as part of standard compliance. To get into bios you can/should use "modern" technology -- press shift while rebooting and then press "reboot to UEFI" settings in Windows bootloader.
https://rivernetcomputers.com/5-ways-windows-10-boot-options-menu/ That is the way nowadays, with Fast Boot activated (so you cannot get in BIOS settings on boot), because of two issues:

1. Security
2. You do not want to initialize USB + Keyboard UEFI capsule drivers and wait precious milliseconds to then initalize Windows drivers.
   Considering my OS boots in 7 seconds -- it is an important part of this.

Comment: That's a new theory, but it doesn't explain why I lost the ability to see the BIOS screen upon updating my video card, while using the same monitor. Also, if it was a power management thing, I'd expect to be able to force the monitor awake by poking at its controls.

Comment: "I lost the ability to see the BIOS" You did not. It is just monitor is not showing it as it is turned off / in sleep. If you press DEL while turning on there is a chance you will get to EUFI BIOS. Try to play with Fast Boot options. But really if it makes the boot faster (not using monitor / USB capsule driver) is not it better? Check how fast the boot is with Ctrl-Shift-Esc --> Autorun in HDMI and DP cases.

Comment: Fast boot is already disabled, and I don't get any display upon actually entering the BIOS either (by mashing F2 on startup on this board). If it were power management, I should be able to switch the monitor to the HDMI input which is active, and then switch back to displayport which should show any DP signal coming through.. but there is no signal.

Comment: "I'd expect to be able to force the monitor awake by poking at its controls" Tell that to Apple LG displays. They do not have any controls.

Answer (score 0):

I could not enter BIOS.  Win 10, ALIENWARE R9 w/ RTX2080 super, ACER XV273K monitor.  My monitor OSD "source" was set to "DP1."  I have 2 DP cables installed (DP1 & DP2).  This computer also had problems waking from sleep.  The solution: Set "source" to "auto."  Both problems went away.

The down side of this:  booting takes a few seconds longer due to the monitor running through all the source options. Cost/benefit is still a plus.

Comment: This won't affect booting speed. The computer doesn't wait for monitor to find the signal, it just carries on as usual. You can perceive it as slower, but that's not actually the case.

Answer (score -1):

I reinstalled my vbios drivers with only my dp port plugged in and it solved the problem. Worked after I rebooted it twice.

Asus Apex VII Motherboard , with a dell rtx 3080 in it.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this issue by disabling CMS in BIOS.
Board: Gigabyte A520i.
CPU: 5600G
GPU: 5600G. I use graphic output of the APU.

Comment: Mentioned in the question as the first thing I tried already.