# Can't POST when UWQHD display connected via DisplayPort

Tags: hdmi, uefi, displayport, post, 4k-resolution

I'm using the [LC-M34-UWQHD-144C](https://www.lc-power.com/en/product/pc-monitors/curved-screens/lc-m34-uwqhd-144-c/) monitor connected via DisplayPort.  My devices are a

1. Thinkpad T480s with a [i5-8250U](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/124967/intel-core-i58250u-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz.html) on a [Thinkpad Ultra 40AJ 0135](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/accessories-and-software/docking/mechanical-docks/40aj0135us) dock, set-up to use a longer boot-time to find monitors; and a
2. [Asus H170I-PLUS D3](https://www.asus.com/us/SupportOnly/H170IPLUS_D3/) with a [i3 6100U](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/90729/intel-core-i36100-processor-3m-cache-3-70-ghz.html).

Both systems run the most recent firmware and boot via UEFI.

In both cases, if I connect the monitor via the HDMI cable, the systems POST and boot fine.  However, if I connect the monitor via DP, the systems won't even POST and I have to hard-reset them.

Otherwise DP works fine:  If I boot via HDMI connected and only then connect the cable I can switch from HDMI to DP just fine.

The closest issue I can find is the one described here:
[Can't get into the BIOS/UEFI or see boot output on DisplayPort, but can on HDMI (ASUS Maximus IX Hero)](https://superuser.com/questions/1522035)

However, I can't even use Windows->reboot to firmware interface nor `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` on Linux to enter the UEFI as described as a workaround there.

Finally, this issue only arises on the above-mentioned 4K/UWQHD monitor.  A regular 16:9 FHD monitor works fine, even when connected with DP.